# TCP NODE JS MULTITHREADING ISSUE

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, tcp, transactions

My code is written on TCP Node JS and its working fine except some multithreading. The other socket is not connected to the server during the first socket transaction for E.g

> Code:-

```
// Start a TCP Server
var clientServer = net.createServer(function (socket) {

  socket.setEncoding('UTF-8');
  socket.on('data',function(data) {

        if(tryParseJSON(data) === false){

            if(data.length != 0){
                transferDataRequest.call({},data,socket);
            }else{

                response = JSON.stringify({Message:'Invalid JSON Object',Response:'Error',result:data});
                response = response+addition_response;
                socket.write(response);
            }

        }else{

            var output = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i in output){
                switch(i){
                    case "newConnection":
                        newConnection.call({},output[i],socket);
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
  });




}).listen(3000,"10.1.28.61");
// Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
console.log("Sever listing at 3000 port\n");



newConnection = function(data,socket){

    var i = 0;
    do {
        i++;
        console.log(1);
    }
    while (i = Math.random());
}
```

[image]
Your response in this regard it will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript code is executed in a single thread in node.js. Your `newConnection` function blocks this thread (`Math.random()` may return 0, but probability is very low).

Comment: its an example do you have any alternate approach in this regard please reply me